# How to partially apply an active pattern

Tags: f#, active-pattern

The `Fsharpx.Extras` NuGet package exposes an active pattern for regular expression matching, qualified as `Fsharpx.Text.Regex.Match`.

The first parameter is a RegexOptions value from the BCL.

Rather than having to write:

```
let someFunc =
    | Match RegexOptions.None "...pattern 1..." matches -> ...
    | Match RegexOptions.None "...pattern 2..." matches -> ...
    | Match RegexOptions.None "...pattern 3..." matches -> ...
    ...
```

I was *hoping* it would be possible to instead have (using a revised `Match'` active pattern):

```
let someFunc =
    | Match' "...pattern 1..." matches -> ...
    | Match' "...pattern 2..." matches -> ...
    | Match' "...pattern 3..." matches -> ...
    ...
```

One possible definition of `Match'` I came up with was:

```
let (|Match'|_|) pattern =
    function
    | Match RegexOptions.None pattern matches -> Some matches
    | _ -> None
```

...which works fine. However, I couldn't help wonder if there was another approach similar to a partially applied function such as:

```
let (|Match'|_|) =
    Match RegexOptions.None
```

Frustratingly, this complains about `Type has no accessible object constructors.`.

**Is something similar to the latter (alebit failing) approach possible?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the Regex module, then change your last example to

```
let (|Match|_|) = (|Match|_|) RegexOptions.None
```

In fact, if you look at the source code, you'll see an example of this in the Compiled module.

https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpx.Extras/blob/master/src/FSharpx.Extras/Regex.fs

Comment: Thank you... Also great spot regarding an example of this in the source code... It didn't even occur to me to check there. Much appreciated!